# How to get the version of JQuery when I use bower to solve the dependencies of js frameworks each other?

Tags: javascript, bower

I'm using bower to solve the dependencies for js frameworks each other?

Now, I want to copy the js file in `bower_components` to the other directory like this `/####/` + the version of js framework/`###.js`.

The question is how I get the version of the js framework.

Anyone can help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I use the module grunt-version-copy-bower-components, It is awesome except that it copy more js file to the dest from bower_components directory.

Comment: Did you answer yourself or what?

Comment: Yes, no one answer me. I answered it when I solve my problem.